# Apple apps are not free anymore for new iPad Air

Tags: ios, ios-appstore, photos.app, keynote, ipad

I recently bought an iPad Air, as as I launched App Store for the first time it gave me an offer to [download premium apple apps for free](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5913). Though I clicked on download now but due to slow connection they couldn't. Now when I search for same apps, it shows me a price on it.

How can I download them now for free?

Comment: Any of the apps that you already purchased won't be available for free, but you can download the latest version of those apps for free. ? Since you started the download that cause the issue you have.

Answer (score 1):

Contact iTunes and request help:

https://ssl.apple.com/emea/support/itunes/contact.html

or try this

```
Sign out from App store
Restart iPad
Go to App store and DO NOT SIGN IN..
Go to app and hopefully you'll see the 'free' button, tap it and sign in when asked.
```